# Apply order by on a joining table field in eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a query which joins one table with another one in a one to one relation. How can I sort the result by a column in the joining relation

```
$relation = ModelObject::where('status', '=', 1)
                            ->with('related_table')
                            ->get()
```

I need to sort this with a column(Eg: name) of `related_table`. How to do this in eloquent.

Comment: `->orderBy('related_table.field');`

Comment: use `->orderBy('table.column_name');`

Comment: this package can help you : https://github.com/fico7489/laravel-eloquent-join

Answer (score 2):

you may use this

```
 $categories = Category::select(DB::raw('categories.*, count(*) as 
`aggregate`'))
->join('pictures', 'categories.id', '=', 'pictures.category_id')
->groupBy('category_id')
->orderBy('aggregate', 'desc');
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships) you can add additional constraints like this,

**Constraining Eager Loads**

Sometimes you may wish to eager load a relationship, but also specify additional query constraints for the eager loading query. Here's an example:

```
$users = App\User::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('title', 'like', '%first%');
}])->get();
```

Finally your code should be something like this,

```
$relation = ModelObject::where('status', '=', 1)
->with(['related_table' => function($query) {
        $query->orderBy('field', 'asc|desc');
}])
->get()
```

Comment: The orderBy() restriction does not apply to parent level of Eloquent

Comment: Thanks, This saved me

Comment: Why not use the relationship of the models?
`$userpost = $user->posts()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();`